# Qt | Работа с layout'ами

Tags: c++, qt, layout

Есть `QTabWidget`. В его вкладку нужно добавить виджет, например `QLabel`. Вкладка представляет собой просто виджет, внутри которого лежит `QHBoxLayout`, а внути него Scroll Bar и Spacer.

```
QWidget* tab = ui->tabs->widget(0);

    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel(tab);
    QFont font;
    font.setPixelSize(24);
    lbl->setFont(font);
    lbl->setText("Some Text");

    tab->layout()->addWidget(lbl);
```

По идее, последняя строка `tab->layout()->addWidget(lbl);` как раз добавляет в `layout` на вкладке тот самый `QLabel` слева, но он вставляет текст вне `layout'a` снизу (т.к. стоит вертикальная компоновка.

Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее исправить.

[image: Tab]
[image: Вывод]

Comment: Вот этот виджет (не сам `QTabWidget`, а именно вкладка) у Вас в дизайнере сделан? Приведите скрин иерархии тогда. Или, если вкладка создаётся динамически, то код.

Comment: @alexis031182 да, в дизайнере. А как лучше? Кодом в конструкторе?

Comment: Не то, чтобы лучше, но когда одно так, а другое эдак, то, вероятно, это не слишком удобно. Раз уж есть потребность в динамике части виджета, то и всего его наверное имеет смысл создавать не в дизайнере. Но это лирика. А по сути проблемы: внешне, вроде, всё правильно, но раз по факту это не так, проверьте в свойствах, может вкладке-виджету горизонтальный layout попросту не назначен. Хотя, вот видно на скрине, что родительская связь точно имеется.

Comment: @alexis031182 добавил скрин вывода, весь вечер вчера пытался разобраться в этом, но вроде все так. Проходил дебагером и методом `layout()` он адекватно возвращает указатель на него

Comment: Похоже, что дизайнер городит огород из двух layout'ов вместо одного. Попробуйте в коде, там где получаете указатель на layout, выполнить поиск дочернего объекта. Например: `QHBoxLayout *hlayout = tab->layout()->findChild<QHBoxLayout*>()`. Ну и посмотрите, будет ли указатель нулевым или всё-таки найдёт спрятанный слой.

Comment: @alexis031182 нет, внутри нет вообще никаких layout'ов

Comment: Даже для `QHBoxLayout *hlayout = tab->findChild<QHBoxLayout*>()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в формах, составленных в `QtDesigner`. Перепесил формы руками и все стало нормально работать.

Comment: Так себе ответ...

Comment: @Qwertiy как есть. Понятия не имею почему это происходит в дизайнере. Может кто-то знает, 2 дня есть

Comment: А файлики сравнить?

Comment: @Qwertiy я подозреваю, что это из-за компоновки на формах, что она считается отдельным layout'om. Но я не уверен, а проверять это сейчас времени нет